# Do ALL android devices have an internal SD card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

On the first run of my app, I am downloading a pretty big file to /sdcard/

I already know this can fail if the internal SD card of the user's phone is full or not mounted (e.g. if the phone is connected to a PC as a mass storage device, or has not been properly disconnected from a PC).

**But are there any android devices with NO INTERNAL SD CARD** ? (on which my app would definitely be unusable)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> But are there any android devices with NO INTERNAL SD CARD ? (on which my app would definitely be unusable)

Any device that has the Android Market will have at least 2GB of storage at `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Whether that is an SD card or something else will vary by device.

Comment: So if the external storage is not an SD card, then the folder /sdcard/ will not be accessible ?

Comment: @Sebastien: **Always** use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to find the root of external storage from code. Your application should not and cannot care whether the "external storage" is an SD card, on-board flash, a hard drive, or cuneiform written on clay tablets. But the root directory varies by device and OS level, and so is not `/sdcard` in all cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this method instead of hardcoding the "/sdcard" path.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  A first generation android phone from which the user has removed/lost/never installed the SD card will not have any external storage, period.  As noted in the question, this will also be the case while the external storage is mounted over USB.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: I was speaking of device capability.

Comment: What do you mean "speaking of device capability"? Is your answer valid only for certain API levels?

Comment: @trusktr: No, but as Mr. Stratton noted, there are occasions where a device will not have external storage, even if it shipped with external storage from the factory (e.g., external storage is removable and has been removed).

Comment: I see. So but at the very least, can we assume that a phone supporting Google Play comes with either built in "external storage" or actual external storage (sdcard, etc)?

Comment: @trusktr: Yes. In order to qualify for Google Play Store, you must have a minimum amount of external storage. You can check the CDD on the AOSP site, but I think it is 1GB nowadays.

Comment: Is there an official black-on-white sentence on the developer site or somewhere else to confirm this statement? Kind of need to know whether I can safely assume every Android 4.0 device will have a 2-3 mb of 'external' storage free and whether I can rely on them. This statement makes things great, but backing it with source would be awesome : )

Comment: @George: The source is the Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) for whichever Android release you are interested in. You can find these at http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html. That's what I was referring to in my previous comment on this answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks, as it so often happens I found it minutes after asking here. The 'shared' memory requirement is now 1GB for 4.0.3 though.

Answer (score 2):

I personally have Samsung Galaxy Tab and it doesn't have internal SD card (shipped with, can be bought separately I guess).

In my program I call Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory and it seems to provide with internal memory path when no SD card is mounted. So far works, haven't investigated further.

Comment: Can you access the /sdcard/ folder ?

Answer (score 2):

All Android compatible devices supports external storage. This doesn't necessary have to be a SD card, it could be non-removable internal storage.