# Unable to write to the Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, file-io, io, fileoutputstream

Please have a look at the following code

```
File folder = new File("/Main Note/Sub Notes/"+dateStr+"/");
File file = new File(folder+name.getText().toString()+".txt");
    try
    {

        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }

        FileOutputStream outputStream =  openFileOutput(file.getName(),Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        outputStream.write(spokenText.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        Toast.makeText(VoiceNotes.this, "Data Successfully written to: "+file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        Toast.makeText(VoiceNotes.this, "Error in Writing to SD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Here I am trying to write data to the internal memory. This has no errors, displays the data has been written successfully.

But when I navigate to the Internal SD in phone, I don't see any folder or file it created! I guess I have done something wrong, this is the first time I am writing to the internal storage in Android.

Comment: have you given the required permissions in your manifest?

Comment: @contactmeandroid: what permission?

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence mb <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    </uses-permission>

Comment: @Suvitruf: Why write settings?

Comment: @contactmeandroid: That is for External. My question is about Internal

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence i copied it from me application. I have this permission and can write to internal storage =/

Comment: what data are u trying to save? and why are u looking for internal store in particular ?

Comment: @contactmeandroid: Text files created by the user. Internal or external is user's choice.

Comment: it's always better to create a new folder and save the txt files  on a external storage.. by using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File folder = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"/MyFolder/");
```

files will be created in "/data/data/app.package/files/...". But you can see them only if device was rooted

Comment: OK. But apps like Yahoo directly write to the internal storage, and I can see them from the explorer.

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence i think, it's bad behavior to write data in public folder. Application should store data in its own internal storage.

Comment: In many cases, yes. But say you have a camera app - you'll want to be able to save to the SD card, will you not?

Comment: I need to write to the public folder. Because any other app can access the data as well.

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence do you really need to write to Internal Storage? You can write data to external storage, so other app can access the data as well.

Comment: what if the device has no externa storage?

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence i never see Android devices that doesn't have external storage =/

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence btw, any device that has the Android Market will have at least 2GB of storage at Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). Whether that is an SD card or something else will vary by device [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4118448/1991579)

Comment: You have to purchase an SD card for the external storage. But some don't they are satisfied with 1GB internal storage. Go and check devices of people of +50, possibly lecturers. Most don't have, they just don't want to.

Comment: wait. Is there any difference between internal memory and interna storage?

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence in some devices external storage is removable. But on devices like me HTC One S sdcard is not removable. But i steal can write to external storage)

Comment: How to access "/data/data/app.package/files/...".  ?

Comment: In other words, you mean not having an option to write to the internal storage is not an issue, bcs "getExternalStorageDirectory" will use internal if there is no external, right?

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence all devices have at least 2GB of storage at getExternalStorageDirectory().

Answer (score 1):

You want to access the path returned by `getExternalStorageDirectory()` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

Comment: this is for internal, not external

Comment: True, but sadly it is not standardized amongst the Android devices, which SD card is internal and which is external. You will get one of them back but which one depends on your device. If you want to access the internal one in any case, maybe this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203615/why-is-this-code-incorrectly-reporting-free-space-on-my-android-device