# 0 MB SD Card Size is not allowed in AVD

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

When an Android Virtual Machine is configured, it is not allowed to determine SD card size as 0 MB size. Does it mean that all Android devices has to have an SD card having at least 9 MB? if so, I will be very happy, because my application stores its bitmap file on only SD card :).

Thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing as an SD card of 0MB, but if you put nothing in your palm, close your fingers around it, and pretend to have an SD card in there, you'll have a 0MB SD card that cannot store your application's bitmap files! Android devices are not required to have any SD card at all.

Comment: No, that's not what i means. there are many Android devices without SD-Cards, however most have the /sdcard storage area anyway

Comment: I found the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118436/do-all-android-devices-have-an-internal-sd-card

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you leave the size field blank, you will get an AVD with no external storage.